# Url parameter read twice so language service cant pick

Tags: angular5, angular2-routing, angular6

**Updated**

I am working on angular5 application where I need to take some data from URL query string.

I am able to get the data but somehow I am getting undefined value which is converted into my expected value later. I want to use this data from query string to decided what language is to be used.

Translate service is working fine if I hardcode .The code is working fine if I hardcode the value in translate.use('en'); I want to assign this value by reading from query string

So basically I want translate.use(this.id) (this.id from url to be passed from query string).

**app.component**

```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
      <label>
        {{ 'HOME.SELECT' | translate }}

      </label>
    </div>

  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  id: string;
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    //const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    //translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use('en');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      this.id = params['id'];
    })
}
}
```

**Calling  way**- http://localhost:4200/?id=en or http://localhost:4200/?id=fr

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I also have i18n folder with json translations.
The code is working fine if I hardcode the value in  `translate.use('en');`
I want to assign this value by reading from query string

So basically I want  **translate.use(this.id)** (this.id from url to be passed from query string).

[image: logged output]

Comment: can you include your routing configuration too?

Comment: I have no routing configuration.i do not have many methods or route.I have one route and want to fetch data from url string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake.
Th code was fine but What I was doing was using ng onit to get data from purl string and constructor to inject translation service and was trying to exchange data between thhose two .Since I could not get any way/getting error ,I added both in constructor and removed onit for getting url parameter(I know Silly!)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppGlobals } from '../app/app.global';;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
      <label>
        {{ 'HOME.SELECT' | translate }}

      </label>
    </div>

  `,
  providers: [ AppGlobals]
})
export class AppComponent {
  param1: string;

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService,private route: ActivatedRoute,private _global: AppGlobals) {
    console.log('Called Constructor');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.param1 = params['param1'];

        translate.use(this.param1);
    });
   // this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

     // this._global.id = params['id'];
      //console.log('hello'+this._global.id);

    //})

    //translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    //translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    //const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    //translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    //const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    console.log('hello'+this._global.id);
    translate.use(this._global.id);
  }
  ngOnInit() {

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not use **?** in routing, instead it uses **;** for [multiple parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero)

> The optional route parameters are not separated by "?" and "&" as they
>   would be in the URL query string. They are separated by semicolons ";"
>   This is matrix URL notation—something you may not have seen before.

In your case, you are passing a single parameter. So Your route should be similar to

```
{path: ':param1' component: AppComponent}
```

Then you would be able to access the **param1** using the code written in `ngOnInit` method. The code should be as shown below

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>console.log(params['param1']));
}
```

If you are planning to use query parameters, then you should use `queryParams` from `ActivateRoute` and url should be **http://localhost:4216/?param1=en** and use below code to access data

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params=>console.log(params['param1']));
}
```

Also including a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-85739y)

Comment: I do not intent to use routing.I want it to be simple to fetch one parameter from url query string

Comment: Thanks  but i am getting this error  " Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'."

Comment: what code did you try, the one mentioned in the question or the one in the answer?

Comment: Mentioned in answer